# Looking for the correct "boundary" value to use in Microsoft Dynamics Web API Batch Changesets

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, changeset

According to Microsoft's documentation found here: [API Batch Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/execute-batch-operations-using-web-api)

When performing changeset batch operations, I need to set up a POST request and include a specific header structure as follows:

```
POST [Organization Uri]/api/data/v9.2/$batch HTTP/1.1
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
If-None-Match: null
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="batch_<unique value/guid>"
```

However, I was only able to get it to work by using this in the Content-Type:

`boundary="changeset_<unique value/guid>"`

And I'm wondering if that is actually what I am supposed to do, perhaps the documentation could be slightly off, or my code is off. I'm doing this programmatically in a C# Azure Function project.

I've tried following the documentation's header structure but was unable to get changesets working with that "batch_" boundary prefix. It would end up becoming an HTTP 400 Bad Request error. It seems to work OK when using "changeset_" as the boundary prefix, but I'm just trying to make sure.